# Sendgrid Java Not working in Maven

Tags: java, api, maven, sendgrid

I am using https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java in my app. When I tried to run a sendgridexample.java its causing error InvocationTargetException and the root cause is

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder
    com.sendgrid.SendGrid.<init>(SendGrid.java:80)` 
I am using maven. Is there anyone tried this in maven. I tried reaching the sendgrid support team but still didn't get any update regarding this. Can any one tell what is wrong with my code. Thanks in advance.

```
SendGrid sendgrid = new SendGrid("API_KEY");
SendGrid.Email email = new SendGrid.Email();

email.addTo("user@domain.com");
email.setFrom("otheruser@domain.com");
email.setSubject("Hello World");
email.setText("My first email with SendGrid Java!");

try {
  SendGrid.Response response = sendgrid.send(email);
  System.out.println(response.getMessage());
}
catch (SendGridException e) {
  System.err.println(e);
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution around this? Is it an Android project? I am having similar issues here..Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have found a solution. Go to https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/tree/master/src/main/java/com/sendgrid. Copy the two java file[SendGrid.java and SendGridException.java] and create a folder com.sendgrid in your application and paste these two java file inside that folder. Then go to https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-java/blob/master/pom.xml. Copy all the dependency for these two java file and paste in your pom.xml file. It will work fine.